# Loop Paragraph types with all values in field--field-page-detail-paragraph.html.twig

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I have two paragraph types called **First Type & Second Type** and added Image & Text fields on it separately. I have created the basic page & added the two above paragraphs(First Type & Second Type) with multiple values.

Its showing only one value of each paragraph, but I have multiple values. So mainly its not rendering/iterate the values properly.

Here is my **field--field-page-detail-paragraph.html.twig file**

```
   {% set first = {} %}
    {% set second = {} %}

{% for key, item in items %} // looking for the bundle items to display

        {% set bundle = item.content['#paragraph'].type.target_id %}

        {% if bundle == "first_type" %}
            {% set first = item.content %}

        {% elseif bundle == "second_type" %}
            {% set second = item.content %}

        {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

    <section class="home">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span8">
                    {{ first }}
                </div>                   
                <div class="span4">
                    {{ second }}
                </div>                 
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**paragraph--first-type.html.twig file**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            {{ content.field_message }}
            {{ content.field_image }}
        </div>                            
    </div>
```

**paragraph--second-type.html.twig file**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            {{ content.field_test }}
            {{ content.field_link }}
        </div>                            
    </div>
```

Can anyone let me know what's issue & how to display all values.

Comment: You overwrite the array variable with item.content instead of pushing it, see https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/622/how-to-push-an-item-to-an-array-in-twig-easily

Comment: @4k4 Can you please explain in detail?